# Как правильно написать? Или правильно и так и так?

Tags: орфография

*Поздравляю с Днём рожденья! Желаю счастья!*

"С днём рожден**ь**я" или "с днём рожден**и**я"?

Comment: *В об**о**их случаях,* а не *в обеих* — "случай" ведь мужского рода.

Answer (score 1):

1. Думаю, говорить, что слова "рожден**ь**е" нет, не совсем правильно.

Используется оно в художественной (особенно поэтической) речи, в которой даже допустима форма *рожде́ньи* (П. п., ед. ч.).
Встречается и в [словаре Ушакова](https://endic.ru/ozhegov/Rozhdenie-30455.html):
*Отселе я вижу потоков рожденье* (Пушкин).
*Ругай меня, я сам кляну свое рожденье* (Грибоедов).

2. Конечно же, в литературном языке правильно *с днём* (чего? Р. п.) *рожден**и**я*.

Вот разъяснения [Грамоты](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F).

Вопрос № 268581. И есть ли принципиальная разница между День рожденЬя или рожденИя?
**Ответ.** День рождения — нейтральный вариант. День рожденья — разговорный. Принципиальной разницы нет.

**Ответ.** Нормативно: день рождения. В разговорной речи возможно: день рожденья (тот самый, который "только раз в году").

*Я играю на гармошке

У прохожих на виду...

К сожаленью, день рожденья

Только раз в году.*
А. Тимофеевский

**Ответ.** Вариант *день рождения* нейтральный, второй вариант [*день рожденья*] характерен для разговорной речи и поэтических текстов.

*День рожденья — праздник детства,

И никуда, никуда, никуда от него не деться.

День рожденья — грустный праздник,

Ты улыбнись, улыбнись, улыбнись, не грусти напрасно.*
П. Жагун

3. В официальном поздравлении пишите "с днем рожден**и**я", а вот приятелю, лучшему другу или хорошей знакомой — можно и "с днем рожден**ь**я".

Answer (score 0):

*Рождение* пишется через И, а не Ь (см. [тут](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5)), поэтому правильно: *"С днём рожден**и**я!"*

Только что заметил, что вы написали "день" с большой буквы. Вообще, строго принято его писать с маленькой в этом случае, с большой он пишется в названии государственных праздников, например *День Победы, День города.*